# How to pass a String argument to a custom pallet function?

Tags: polkadot, pallet, substrate-node-template

In the below code, I'm passing something of u32 type. How can I pass a text(String) instead of u32?

```
pub fn do_something(origin, something: u32) -> dispatch::DispatchResult {
            
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            // Update storage.
            Something::put(something);

            // Emit an event.
            Self::deposit_event(RawEvent::SomethingStored(something, who));
            // Return a successful DispatchResult
            Ok(())
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` is a special `Vec<u8>` actually.

You could use `Vec<u8>`.

---

Actually, we can use `String`.

```rust
extern crate alloc;

use alloc::string::String;
```

But we don't do that. It makes things complicated.

As I said, `String` is a `Vec<u8>`. You could do anything with `Vec<u8>`.

`b"hello world".to_vec()` is also a `Vec<u8>`.

There is no `println!` in no_std. So, you don't need the `Display`.

If you want to log something you could use `#[cfg(features = "std")]`, then you can use `String`.

For events, you could let apps decode the `Vec<u8>` to `String`. That's not our job.

IMO, `Vec<u8>` is more efficient.

Comment: U know any reason, Why we can't use String?

Comment: @Samray Because Substrate uses `no_std` so there's no `String` type.

Comment: I updated my anwser.